# innerHtml not working for nested div tags

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, getelementbyid

I am not able to replace .innerHtml for a div tag which is nested in other div tags. I used firebug to make sure that getElementById() is working.

```
<div class="a">
<div class="b"><a href="myUrl"><div id="hello"></div></a></div>
</div>
```

In javascript code I am using:

```
document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML = "hello world";
```

Using firebug, I have verified that "hello" div is picked up (that is, it is not null). But the string "hello world" is not showing up.
Kindly help.
Thanks.

Comment: Do NOT put a div container inside an a element. Your DOM should be like this: <div><a>Link</a></div>. It isn't related to the problem you're having, but you *will* be flamed for it.

Comment: I am using innerHTML. That was a typo in question.

Comment: [Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2RZNR/) showing that your code already works. I'd start looking for another "hello" id somewhere on the page.

Comment: If you're saying it was just a typo in the question, and it still doesn't work, there's something stopping your JavaScript from executing. An error, perhaps. This works flawlessly ([here](http://jsfiddle.net/GMej3/)).

Comment: @Amaan in HTML5 that is no longer true.  The content model for `<a>` tags in HTML5 is *transparent*, which means essentially that it inherits its content model from a non-transparent parent element

Comment: I am pretty sure my javascript is executing. Also I have also tried with a really unique id (="abkdelsdkield" etc.). Also go add, the outermost div has a dojoType attribute.

Comment: @Pointy Really? That's good to know. Any suggestions for where I could read more about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `innerHTML` rather than `innerHtml`. note the capitalization.

On a side note, IE also supports `innerText`.

Answer (score 2):

The example you provided works for me... so, I think you should make sure that the script is executed after the element has been created in the DOM.

For example, place the script element after the div you want to add contents to.
So if this fixes the issue, then you should add an event listener to the window’s onload event which will run all scripts.

And as Amaan said, don’t place a **div** element inside an **a** element.

Comment: I have placed div outside of <a> element. I have also placed the js code after the div tag. In order to verify that the div is being picked up I used: var x = document.getElementById("hello"); and made sure x was not null.

Comment: My bad, there was a typo. It is working after fixing that typo and placing the <div> and <a> tags correctly. Thanks!